# Apache storm final bolt that should not emit tuples?

Tags: apache-storm

Assuming we have the following topology

```
spout A -> bolt B -> bolt C -> bolt E
```

and **bolt E** is the final one, that persists info in the *database*, therefore no needs to emit any tuple. How to implement such solution,

if I define no **output_fields** - then I get exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: org.apache.storm.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'output_fields' is unset! Struct:StreamInfo(output_fields:null, direct:false)
        at storm.petrel.ThriftReader.read(ThriftReader.java:77)
        at storm.petrel.GenericTopology.readTopology(GenericTopology.java:36)
        at storm.petrel.GenericTopology.main(GenericTopology.java:53)
Caused by: org.apache.storm.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'output_fields' is unset! Struct:StreamInfo(output_fields:null, direct:false)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.StreamInfo.validate(StreamInfo.java:407)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.StreamInfo$StreamInfoStandardScheme.read(StreamInfo.java:485)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.StreamInfo$StreamInfoStandardScheme.read(StreamInfo.java:441)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.StreamInfo.read(StreamInfo.java:377)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.ComponentCommon$ComponentCommonStandardScheme.read(ComponentCommon.java:681)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.ComponentCommon$ComponentCommonStandardScheme.read(ComponentCommon.java:636)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.ComponentCommon.read(ComponentCommon.java:552)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.Bolt$BoltStandardScheme.read(Bolt.java:451)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.Bolt$BoltStandardScheme.read(Bolt.java:427)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.Bolt.read(Bolt.java:358)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.StormTopology$StormTopologyStandardScheme.read(StormTopology.java:727)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.StormTopology$StormTopologyStandardScheme.read(StormTopology.java:683)
        at org.apache.storm.generated.StormTopology.read(StormTopology.java:595)
        at storm.petrel.ThriftReader.read(ThriftReader.java:75)
        ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Please re-check bolt E, make sure it was not set by any others bolt (it's meant bolt E was not used by any methods TopologyBuilder.setBolt, e.g. : TopologyBuilder.setBolt("mybolt",new MyBolt()).fieldsGrouping("bolt E",
                new Fields(new String[] { "user_id" }));